# Unity3d iOS: unable to find iPhone_GlesSupport.h

Tags: unity, xcode

i've an old unity project and i've tried it just today (with unity 4.1) and xcode 4.6.
Xcode is unable to build it for the error: "iPhone_GlesSupport.h" file not found.

Im pretty a noob under xcode and objective-c in general so i've searched in internet about this problem, but without any luck.

Anyone know more or have experienced this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us your library search path / header include / equivalent? We'll most likely need that to help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421028/everyplay-broken-with-unity3d-4-1-iphone-glessupport-h-missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Unity 4.1 changed the trampoline project pretty significantly.  There must be a plugin or something that your older project is using that is referencing that old file and needs to be updated to Unity 4.1.

Comment: yep, i've fixed my problem in this way: i've just started another project with the same old files and now work. Mystery of Unity (and of his poor documentation :) )